# Can I extend a drain pipe after the concrete around it has set?

Tags: repair, drain

I put in new cement floor in shower stall. I now realize that the pipe is too low. How can I extend the PVC drain pipe?

Comment: Pictures are always helpful so we can see what you ee.

Comment: If the floor is too low, that means the drain is too high.  Why would you need to *extend* something that's already too high?  Unless this is an ESL issue.

Comment: Welcome. I took a crack at fixing your terminology and logic. Please revise further as needed. Also, take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 3):

Chisel out some concrete around the pipe, add a coupling and more pipe.

That is very easy within 24-48 hours of pouring it, as it's quite weak, having not cured yet (set and cured are different things for concrete.)

The same can be done even after it's cured - concrete is not immutable - but it's *easier* if you get to it before it's fully cured.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is the drain is flush with the concrete and now you have to add to it, try an [internal PVC pipe connector](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/plumbing/pipe-fittings/plastic-fittings/4512315?store=16864&gclid=Cj0KCQjw0tKiBhC6ARIsAAOXutmnpLSf-76rzqEcR0Ma_nd-A870lCn5r7Oew808qX1JK99EElO6TbAaAiwwEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Shower drains should be 2" if somehow you have a different size, other sizes are available.

Comment: This works in a pinch, but it effectively reduces pipe size and creates a potential clog point.

Comment: @isherwood, The reduction is miniscule.

Comment: Actually, if you do the actual math, assuming an actual wall thickness of 1/8", the actual reduction in area is ~24%. That's actually surprising, eh?

Comment: you know what happens when you assume.